# throw new Exception returns wrong line number

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

When I try to get the stack trace by throwing an exception , I see the line number is the exact line of the "e.getMessage()" instead of the line of the throw statement. this only happens if I have e.getMessage() in the statement. is that right behavior ?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 10;
    calculateX(x);

}

private static void calculateX(int x) {

    try {
        throw new ArithmeticException("" +
                "divide by 0");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Run time error "

                + e.getMessage()
                , e);
    }
}
```

stack trace :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Run time error divide by 0
    at com.myTest.Main.calculateX(Main.java:49)
    at com.myTest.Main.main(Main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by 0
    at com.myTest.Main.calculateX(Main.java:44)
    ... 1 more
```

line 49 is the e.getMessage line

Comment: That's... interesting. The behaviour is triggered by the line break(s) in the `String`-concatenation. [With linebreak (Ideone demo)](https://ideone.com/LDVkr4) --- [Without linebreak (Ideone demo)](https://ideone.com/K5NruS)

Comment: No line numbers change if run with JDK16

Answer (score 1):

What happen is,
[image: ![main method with lines]

when run the above code you will get something like this,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Run time error divide by 0
    at com.maneesha.Main.calculateX(Main.java:17)
    at com.maneesha.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by 0
    at com.maneesha.Main.calculateX(Main.java:15)
    ... 1 more
```

if we look at the lines first it happens in the method call `calculateX()` and in the `try` block it will throw the `ArithmeticException` and it will catch by the `catch` block then throws the `RuntimeException`, and what happens is we catch the error we expecting and throw it as a new error that's why you able to see the error on line 17.

So if you read the full stack trace you will be able to identify which causes the error. Also, it is good practice not to catch `Exception` and catch the specific errors, because `catch(Exception e)` will catch all the errors.